# Is $x/x$ continuous at $0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Just wondering, while studying limit, if $x\over x$ is continuous at $0$. $f(0)={0 \over 0}$ ,, but $x/x=1$. In this case, is it continuous at $0$?

Comment: What **exactly** is your definition of the function $\;\frac xx\;$ on the real line and, in particular, at $\;x=0\;$ ?

Comment: @Timbuc, it does not matter how you define or not define the function at $x = 0.$ the limit is $1.$

Comment: @abel yes, whether the function is continuous however depends on its value at $0$.

Comment: ...what is $p$?

Comment: @abel, I think I know that, yet that was **not** the question.

Comment: the function $x/x$ is not even defined at $x=0$, though it can be uniquely extended to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ by virtue of the fact it only has a *removable*, isolated singularity. this is the idea behind [holomorphic extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity)

Comment: @daOnlyBG given that "p" is close to "0" on various keyboards, as well as other considerations, it should be $0$ in all likelihood.

Comment: Despite the kind of "clueless" nature of this question, I don't think that it deserves the down-votes (and in a certain way, the well elaborated answer below proves it).

Answer (score 14):

The question is not quite precise but:

- The limit $\lim_{x \to 0} x/x$ exists and is $1$.
- The function $x \mapsto x/x$ for $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0 \}$ is not defined at $0$ and it makes no sense to ask about its continuity there.
- The function $x \mapsto x/x$ for $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0 \}$ can be extended to a function on $\mathbb R$ via defining it to be $1$ for $x=0$. This is then obviously a continuous function. One could also extend it in some other way, in which case it would not be continuous.

Comment: Great answer. I was trying to push the OP towards something like this. +1

Comment: Might have not up voted if not for "makes no sense to ask about continuity here". Time and again people will make the mistake of saying it is discontinuous in this case.

Comment: @GitGud Then ask "Is the square root continuous at 'shoe'?"

Comment: @GitGud Doesn't that depend on how you use the definitions and terms? The definition I know is, a function $f$ is continuous at $c$ iff $f(c)$ is defined, $\lim_{x\to c}$ exists, and $\lim_{x\to c}=f(c)$. In this case, $f(0)$ is not defined, so $f$ is not continuous at $0$. If "discontinuous at $c$" simply means "not continuous at $c$," then isn't $f$ discontinuous at $0$? On the other hand, the whole function is continuous when it is continuous at every point in the domain, and $f$ is continuous, since $0$ is not in its domain. An easy source of confusion, but is my first statement wrong?

Comment: @DanielFischer To me that question makes no sense.

Comment: @GitGud That's the point. Asking whether a function is continuous at a point outside its domain makes no sense. If you use a sufficiently absurd example, you might get the point across.

Comment: @KSmarts I agree with you. But many times the definition goes like "given $c$ in the domain of $f$ (...)". using this definition, if you're not given $c$ is the domain, there's nothing you can say, it's senseless.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, I see. I thought you were disagreeing with me.

Comment: @GitGud It reminds me of a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1087623/75923) I asked myself.

Comment: I think many authors use "discontinuity point" even at points not in the domain of definition **but** for which there is at last some one-sided non-trivial neighborhood where the  function's defined, e.g.: $\;\frac{\sin x}x\;$ is discontinuous at $\;x=0\;$ . Yes, $\;x=0\;$ is **not** a *natural* definition point of this function, yet it has a non-trivial neighborhood where the function is defined. Something similar to vertical asymptotes of functions. A matter of (dis)agreement, I think.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f$ is continuous at $c$ iff $f(c)$ exists, and $f(c)=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$.

In your example, $f(x)=\frac xx$ and $c=0$. Since $f(c)$ does not exist, your function is not continuos at that point.