# If $\tan x$ is not a differentiable function then why does its differentiation $\sec^2(x)$ exists?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

$\tan x$ is not differentiable at $(2n + 1)90$ points, which means function itself is not differentiable. So, why does its differentiation $\sec^2(x)$ exists?

Comment: Now, why would you downvote it? My question could be dumb but anybody can have doubts.

Comment: The expression $\tan x$ is not a function, $\tan$ is. And $\tan$ is differentiable at every point in its domain, so it is differentiable.

Comment: $\sec^2x$ is not defined at these points either.

Comment: @GitGud tan is not differentiable at 90 degree, since it is not continuous. Am i wrong?

Comment: @user2409011 tan is not defined at 90 degrees. So, there is no question of it being continuos or differentiable. It's just not defined.

Comment: @user2409011 Differentiability only makes sense in points of the domain of the given function. It doesn't make sense to talk about differentiability or  non-differentiability of $\tan$ at $90º$. It's not that $\tan$ isn't differentiable there, it's that that concept doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @user2409011 Perhaps [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1116868) answer and the comments below it will help you understand.

Comment: This is a duplicate question and has been asked many times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You derive $\tan(x)$ on its domain, not on any point of $\mathbb{R}$!

Also, note that $\sec^2(x) = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$ is not defined at $x= \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$, which is coherent with the fact that $\tan(x)$ isn't too.

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{1}{\color{red}{\cos}^2x}$?

Comment: But of course, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 2):

Differentiation here is defined only on those points of $\tan x$ which are differentiable. In the regions where the function is differentiable, It has a derivative equal to $\sec^2(x)$