# multivariable limit problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have a confusion regarding this problem.

**Problem:** $\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{\sin^2|x+2y|}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous for all  $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. True or false?

I think that the limit does not exist so the function is not continuous.

How to prove that limit does not exist?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: "I think that the limit does not exist so the function is not continuous. How to prove that limit does not exist?" What limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try approaching the limit by the line $y=k\cdot x$.

Applying the standard limit $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(t)}{t}$$
You can prove that the limit depends on the constant K, hence does not exist

Comment: The function is not continuous at $(0,0)$ even if the limit does exist. Is the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: @KittyL It doesn't make sense to consider continuity outside the domain of a function. So you can't say it's discontinuous there, it simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GitGud: Then why shall we prove that the limit does not exist? For example, if we are asked to prove the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ is continuous at all $x$ except $0$?

Comment: @KittyL I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think I understand that it does not make sense to say it is discontinuous at $(0,0)$. So we wouldn't need to prove it by using limit, right? Because $(0,0)$ is apparently out of its domain.

Comment: @KittyL Yes, there's nothing to prove because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087623/is-function-f-mathbb-c-0-rightarrow-mathbb-c-prescribed-by-z-rightarrow) question.