# Show $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$ is discontinuous at x=0

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling to explicitly show that the function is discontinuous at $x=0$ since the usual technique of finding two sequences $x_n$,$y_n$ where $x_n\rightarrow0$, $y_n\rightarrow0$ but $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_n)$ tend to different values, doesnt seem to work as all seuqnces tend to $+\infty$.

My only other thought would be that since $f(0)$ doesn't exist, then from this $f(x)$ cannot be continuous. But I'm unsure if this would suffice as an answer.

Comment: The function $\frac{1}{|x|}$ is not defined at $x=0$, and so you cannot ask whether it is continuous there. It is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we talk about the continuity/discontinuity of a function at a point which is not in its domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482787/can-we-talk-about-the-continuity-discontinuity-of-a-function-at-a-point-which-is)

Comment: Roughly speaking, the following ensemble of symbols and words: 

 ‘$1/|x| \colon\mathbb R^*\to\mathbb R$ is not continuous in $0$.’

 is no statement, i.e., neither true nor false.

Answer (score 2):

If my students dare to say that this function is discontinuous at $0$, they will miserably fail. But we all know that the definition of *discontinuity* is somehow vague.

1. Many mathematicians clearly state that a function can be discontinuous only at points of the domain. For these people, your work is useless, since your function **is** continuous throughout the domain of definition.
2. Other mathematicians say that a function is *always* discontinuous at points that do not belong to the domain of definition, *but* they are accumulation points for the domain. Indeed, since $f(x_0)=\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ is the characterizing property of continuous functions, it is violated as soon as $f(x_0)$ does not exist. Even in this case your work is useless, since your function is automatically continuous.

I won't write here a long discussion about the "best" definition of discontinuity, since it has been done several times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ then $\displaystyle x_n \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0$ and
$$
f\left(x_n\right) \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}+\infty
$$

Hence $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$

Comment: But $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$ is not definied for $x=0$ so your question is senseless