# Is a continuous function plus a discontinuous function discontinuous?

Tags: limits, continuity

More specifically, I am wondering if $\sin(1/x) - x$ is discontinuous at $0$. I know that $f(x)= \sin(1/x)$ is discontinuous at $0$, but $f(x) = -x$ is continuous at all points. However if I add these two functions together, does that make sum of the function discontinuous?

Comment: If $f+g$ is continuous where $f$ is continuous, then $(f+g)-f=g$ is continuous.

Comment: Actually, many people (including me) wouldn't agree that $\sin(1/x)$ is discontinuous at $0$, since the word "discontinuous" should only be used for points in the function's domain of definition. See discussion here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087623/is-function-f-mathbb-c-0-rightarrow-mathbb-c-prescribed-by-z-rightarrow/1087642#1087642

Comment: Discontinuous in the sense that for any definition of $f(0)$, $f(x) = \sin (1/x)$ is discontinuous at $0$. This is not true for the function $\sin(x)/x$ for example. The latter is sometimes called a "removable" discontinuity.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, we should note that $\sin(1/x)$, as it stands *is* continuous wherever it is defined. By that, I mean that $\sin(1/x)$ is not defined for $x=0$, so we have to assume that $x\neq 0$ when evaluating $\sin(1/x)$. Frequently, we avoid this problem by writing $$g(x)=\begin{cases} \sin(1/x) & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0.\end{cases}$$ This is probably the function you mean to use, or at least something like that. As you note, $g(x)$ is discontinuous at $0$. Suppose that $g(x)+x=f(x)$ was continuous. Then $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Since the difference of continuous functions is continuous, $g(x)$ is continuous. But this is a contradiction. Therefore, $g(x)+x$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: If one agrees with the statement that a continuous function is a function which is continuous at every point in its domain, then $\sin(1/x)+x$ *is* continuous! (But if you extend $\sin(1/x)$ to be defined on the whole real line, by assigning some arbitrary value at the origin, then it becomes discontinous.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Very good point. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Wouldn't the domain without 0 lead to an "almost everywhere" continuity, as there is no way to formulate an epsilon-delta continuity construction for a gapped domain?

Comment: @rubenv We can formulate $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity for any metric space, connected or not. In fact, by removing zero from the domain, the function is in fact everywhere continuous.

Answer (score 11):

If $f$ is continuous and $h$ is continuous then $g=h -f$ is continuous.

So if $f$ is continuous and $g$ is discontinuous $f+g = h$ can not be continuous else $h-f =g$ would also be continuous.

Comment: So continuous +/- continuous = continuous, continuous +/- discontinuous = discontinuous, discontinuous +/- discontinuous = could be anything.

Comment: Pretty much.  And multiplication and division (except at zero).  Basically i) continuous combined "nicely" with contionuous => continuous, ii) discontinuous means nothing other than *not* continuous and in general discontinuity and combinations of discontinuity imply nothing.  *However* as cont % cont => cont then cont % disc = x => cont $\%^{-1}$ x => disc => x is not cont => x is discontinuous by contrapositive.  This is *not* by any characteristic of discontinuity but by the impossibility of the characteristic of continuity.

Comment: Likewise discontinuous % x = continuous usually (not always) implies  x ^ continuous = discontinuous => x is not continuous => x is discontinuous.  (Assuming % is invertable in a way that preserves continuity.)

Answer (score 6):

Recall the definition of continuous. We say a function is continuous at $x_0$, if $f(x_0)$ is well defined, and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)$ exists, where $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$.

We should always define function formally. Let $f:\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$. When we defined $f$ in this way, we have $f$ is a continuous function. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=x$. We have this function is continuous. We cannot simply add $f$ and $g$, since their domain is different. We could restrict the domain of $g$ to the set $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. Where $g|_{\mathbb{R}-\{0\}}+f$ is continuous.

But in general, for any function $g,f:D\rightarrow R$, where $f$ is continuous and $g$ is discontinuous, we have $f+g$ is discontinuous.

Comment: Your 'in general' statement suggests that there are cases in which a continuous function and a discontinuous function can produce a contininuous function, this is never the case. As Samuel had stated: If f+g is continuous where f is continuous, then (f+g)−f=g is continuous.

Comment: +1. This is easily the best answer so far, in my opinion. But for this definition to agree with the usual $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ stuff, one also needs to say explicitly that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if $x_0$ is an isolated point in the domain $D_f$ (in which case it doesn't make sense to talk about $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$).

Comment: @DrunkWolf If something holds in general it means that it holds for the general case, that is without further assumptions.  This means that Eric's final statement states that there are no pair of continuous and discontinuous functions that sum to a continuous function.