# Is sum of continuous and discontinuous function necessarily a discontinuous?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity

It is well established that sum of a continuous function with a discontinuous function is also discontinuous(See this : [Is a continuous function plus a discontinuous function discontinuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1728434/1020656))

However consider this example
(**NOTE** : $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer function.)

$f(x):(0,1){\to}(0,1)$ and $f(x) = x^2$

$g(x):(-\infty,\infty)\to(-\infty,\infty)$ and $g(x)=[x]$ ;

$h(x):(0,1)\to(0,1)$ and $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$

Clearly, $f$ is continuous, $g$ is discontinuous and $h$ is continuous. So, does this disprove that sum of continuous and discontinuous function is necessarily discontinuous?

Comment: No, because $g$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @JohnDouma So? We only have to check continuity of $f$ , $g$ and $h$ **separately** . I have intentionally defined $g$ for a domain greater than $(0,1)$ .

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are two separate functions, their continuity shall be checked out separately.

Comment: The sum $f+g$ is only defined on $(0,1)$. Defining $g$ outside of the definition of the sum is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some authors implicitly restrict the larger domain to fit the smaller, as you did in the example. In this case the corresponding result is that $h$ is continuous if and only if both restrictions of $f$, $g$ to the domain of $h$ are continuous. As you pointed out, it is crucial that we consider the restrictions.

Formally, take $f_i:\mathcal D_i\rightarrow\mathbb R$ for any $\mathcal D_i\subseteq\mathbb R$. Let $\mathcal D=\mathcal D_1\cap\mathcal D_2$ and $h:\mathcal D\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $x\mapsto f_1(x)+f_2(x)$. Now, we already know that for any $x\in\mathcal D$ the sum $h$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous at $x$. This means that $h$ is continuous (on $\mathcal D$) is continuous if and only if both restrictions of $f_1$, $f_2$ to $\mathcal D$ are continuous.

Comment: Why do different authors use different definitions? Can't there be any agreement and meetings among mathematicians to put a standard ( like there is a IUPAC for chemistry) ?

Comment: All authors restrict the domain. The sum of two functions $f+g$ is defined as $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. How would you define the sum of two functions where one is defined on a larger domain?

Comment: @John Douma: When looking at [function spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space), the domain is usually fixed first, say $[0,1]$ for $C([0,1])$, The sum is then introduced as an operator for functions in this space, say $f+g\in C([0,1])$ for $f,g\in C([0,1])$.
If you discuss such a given function space and introduce the sum as an operator, you do not (have to) restrict domains.
But yes, you may consider $C([0,2])\times C([0,1])\rightarrow C([0,1])$, $(f,g)\mapsto f+g$, or formal sums, and some authors do so (if required). Then, the argument by An_Elephant makes sense.

Comment: @An_Elephant: Sometimes, different perspectives make sense. Say, matrices (and vectors) may be considered as points or as operators. Measures are encoded as set functions, cumulative distribution functions, Radon-Nikodym derivatives, push-forwards, sometimes as point in a space. All these interpretations are valid. In our case, we may consider the sum $f+g$ of *any* two functions $f$ and $g$, but only *formally*, as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set), not as an operator. If you want $f+g$ as an operator, you have to restrict the domains, and thus may keep it fixed.

Comment: @JohnDouma I have been taught to take the common domain for the sum of function. See [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Z72.jpg this . It is on wikipedia .