# Can a function with a discontinuous domain be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If I have a function with a domain that has "gaps" in it, can it still be continuous?

For example, consider the piecewise function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x & x\in[-1,0]\\ x-1 & x\in(1,2] \\ \end{cases}$$

With graph:

[image: Graph of function in question]

Is this continuous? From the epsilon-delta definition I would think it is, as the function is not defined in the regions where it "jumps" - but this goes against the naive high school era idea of continuity I had, involving moving a pencil along the function without lifting it off the paper.

Comment: Yes, it's continuous. Another surprising example is the function $x\to\dfrac1x$ defined for $x\in\Bbb R^*$, which is also continuous. Try by any means to forget the naive high school definition: it's just plain wrong.

Comment: You maybe mean a "disconnected" domain, where (dis)connectivity has a certain topological meaning

Comment: I have closed this question as the answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829882/can-a-continuous-function-have-discontinuities are excellent and do in fact answer my question. It seems a shame though that the question there was phrased so poorly and is really quite confusing...