# Why no absolute value for integral of $\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, absolute-value

Problem:

> Find a curve whose slope at each point $(x,y)$ equals the reciprocal of the $x$-value if the curve contains the point $(e,-3)$.

If we call the equation of the curve $f(x)$, then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. $\int \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln|x|+C$, so $f(x)= \ln|x|+C$. $f(e)=-3$ so $f(x)= \ln|x|-4$. What I am confused by is that my book's answer is $f(x)= \ln x-4$ (there are no absolute value bars around $x$). If there are no bars, that means the bars are uneccessary so $x$ must be greater than zero. But what part of the problem indicates that $x$ must be greater than zero?

Comment: the discontinuity at $x=0,$ where the condition on the "slope" does not make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\frac{1}{x}$ is discontinuous (update: Hans Lundmark's comment suggests using "undefined" instead) at $x = 0$, there are actually $2$ curves involved, one where $x \lt 0$ and another where $x \gt 0$. Since the point in question of $(e,-3)$ has $x = e \gt 0$, it's only this positive $x$-values curve which is being asked about. Thus, there's no need for absolute value signs in this case. Nonetheless, I believe the book should still have used absolute values, even if they're not strictly necessary.

Update: After reading the comments below and on further reflection, I now believe it's best to not use absolute values, as this helps to implicitly show the solution is only for $x \gt 0$. I suspect this is a major reason why the book did not use absolute values in their answer.

Comment: How are there 2 curves? The integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ can still be continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: No, it is not continuous.  $\ln(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0+$.  If you want a **connected** curve, the answer is $\ln(x)-4$ for $x > 0$.  There is no reason to include a curve $\ln(-x)+c$ for $x<0$, which is not connected to the first curve; and if you wanted to include one, there's no reason to have $c=-4$.

Comment: @user532874 Note the question says the curve's slope is the reciprocal of the $x$-value. Thus, as $x \to 0^{+}$, the slope will approach positive infinity, with $\ln x$ going to $-\infty$, as Robert Israel stated. Thus, the curve is discontinuous at $x = 0$, so for $x \lt 0$, if you wish to consider that region, it's a different "curve" (i.e., not connected to the first one, as Robert's comment indicates), even if you have one defined function which encompasses both curves.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for your comment & explanation. You did a better job of it than I could.

Comment: This is one illustration of why I consider it unfortunate that calculus students are taught $\int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln |x| + c$.  It really should be $\ln(x) + c_1$ for $x > 0$ and $\ln(-x) + c_2$ for $x < 0$, where there is no connection between $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: I do see now that $\ln x$ is not continuous at zero but I still don’t see why there would be 2 curves. At $x<0$ there are no defined points for $\ln x$.

Comment: @user532874 The curve for $x \gt 0$, & for $x \lt 0$ if you choose to define for that domain, are not connected. Thus, depending on how you define "curve", they are $2$ separate curves. If all you're concerned about is $x \gt 0$, then you can use $\ln x$. However, if you wish to also consider $x \lt 0$, then you need to use something like $\ln |x|$, or $\ln(-x)$ for $x \lt 0$. As Robert's comment states, although it's taught $\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \ln |x| + c$, there are really $2$ curves which should be treated separately, e.g., the $c$ values don't need to match between the $2$ curves.

Comment: @user532874 In particular, the condition $f(e)=-3$ pins down the location of the curve for $x>0,$ but **not** the curve for $x<0.$ The curve could pass through $(-1,0)$ or $(-1,-17)$ or $(-1,9987)$ or infinitely many points all of which force the $x<0$ part to be different from all the other choices. Which one do you choose? The problem statement gives no advice on that, so it seems reasonable that the solution does not either.

Comment: Nitpick: It's best not to use the word *discontinuous* when referring to points where the function is *undefined*, since it's strange to say that continuous(!) functions like $1/x$ or $\ln x$ have discontinuites. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087623/is-function-f-mathbb-c-0-rightarrow-mathbb-c-prescribed-by-z-rightarrow