# Is (x-2)/(x-2) classified as having a removable discontinuity or removable singularity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I learned that if a function is undefined at a point and becomes discontinuous because of that, it is actually a removable singularity, whereas if we set it to be different valued through a piecewise function, it is a removable discontinuity. So by my logic, the function above has a removable singularity at x=2. Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \frac{x-2}{x-2}$ (on the implied domain $\Bbb R\setminus \{2\}$) has a removable *singularity* at $x = 2$. It does not have a discontinuity there (removable or otherwise) because it is a continuous function. For a function to be discontinuous, there *must be a discontinuity* and such a discontinuity *must lie in the domain of the function*, by definition. The point $x = 2$ is not in the domain, and therefore the function cannot possibly be discontinuous there.

Comment: +1. A related discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087623/is-function-f-mathbb-c-0-rightarrow-mathbb-c-prescribed-by-z-rightarrow