# Why is showing a limit doesn't exist useful for multi-variable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Given a multivariable function $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$, we know at the point $f(0,0)$, the function is undefined. So if I were to test for continuity, couldn't I say that this function is non-continuous at the point $(0,0)$ because there is a hole?

I ask this because the correct way to show that the function is discontinuous is by showing that along the axis $y=0$, the limit of the function approaches 1. Along the axis $x=0$, the limit approaches -1, so the function must not be continuous.

Why is it/what is the point of showing the limit doesn't exist along different paths, if we already know that the point is undefined?

Comment: If the limit were the same along all paths, then we could define the value of the function at that point to be said value.

Comment: @Math1000 Even if that said value does not exist because we are dividing by 0?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you assign a value to $f(0,0)$ (“by hand”, not using the formula) it doesn't make sense to ask if the function is continuous or not at that point.
(See discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087623/is-function-f-mathbb-c-0-rightarrow-mathbb-c-prescribed-by-z-rightarrow), for example.)

What does make sense to ask is whether you *can* define $f(0,0)$ so that the function becomes continuous. And in this case you can't, since $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ doesn't exist. That is, the function
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2},& (x,y) \neq (0,0),\\
C,&(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$
is discontinuous at $(0,0)$ no matter what $C$ is.

Answer (score 0):

We say that $f$ is continuous at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ if
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)}f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0).$$
This condition fails if either the limit doesn't exist or $f(x_0,y_0)$ isn't defined. In your case, you know $f(0,0)$ isn't defined, hence, you know $f$ isn't continuous at that point.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same case for functions in one variable, for example $\frac{\sin 2x}{x}$ is undefined at zero, right? But its limit exists at $0$, and it is $2$ so if you took the function
$f(x) = \begin{cases}
      \frac{\sin 2x}{x}  & \text{if $x \ne 0$}\\
      2 & \text{$x=0$}
\end{cases}$ then this will be a continuous function.

Comment: What is the usefulness of the information if we are excluding x = 0?

Comment: What information exactly you see useless? Getting the limit? We use it to define $f(0)$

Comment: I guess my question is this: since f(0,0) is undefined, are we saying the function only applies for non-zero x and y values? And we use the limit to show what the true value of f(0,0) is (if it exists)?

Comment: Yes I think what your saying is right, usually it is stated this way, $f$ is defined for all $x \ne 0$ (i.e. it is undefined for $x=0$) but it has an extension by continuity (only if the limit exists)

Comment: So in reality, with the example you gave, it is undefined at $x=0$. How does knowing the limit at $x=0$ is 2 help us?

Comment: Since this limit exists (is finite) then we concluded that this function can by extended by continuity to $f(x)$. If the limit was infinite then this wouldn't be true. Also extending a function by continuity somehow means that with a very tiny editing the function will be continuous.

Comment: You can check the graph of $\frac {sin x}{x}$ and that of $\frac{1}{x}$ and notice the difference in the cases where the limit exists a d where it doesn't, and how the area under the curve is finite or not, ...