# What is the point of discontinuity for the complex function $f(z)= \frac{2z-3}{z^2+2z+2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone help me find the point of discontinuity of a complex function? $$f(z)= \frac{2z-3}{z^2+2z+2}$$

Comment: It should not be so different from finding the discontinuity of a real function. Figure out what $z$ values make the denominator $0$ and those roots should be points of discontinuity.

Comment: Hint: $z^2+2z+2= (z+1)^2+1$

Answer (score 0):

Is it really a discontinuity point if the function is not even defined on it? For me, this "function" (you didn't specify the domain) is continuous.

Comment: he said it's a complex function, so presumably over C...

that's just a guess though

Comment: well, then he is hiding the values of the function on the poles.

Comment: hello @hellofriends, what do you "hiding the values $\cdots$?"

Comment: well if the function is defined in all the complex numbers. I'm assuming the roots of $z^2 + 2z + 2$ are complex numbers. So the function must be defined on these points. I'm not quite seeing which values the function takes on them, are you?

Comment: he wasn't hiding them. that was literally the question. where are the poles?

Comment: Take a look at  @NinadMunshi's hint to the question.  Also, the poles are given in one of the answers.

Comment: @Reneo the question is what values that expression takes on it's singularities? I must have some eye disease then

Comment: not the values of the function at the singularities, but the values of z that produce singularities

Comment: Sorry, that is not what the question asks.

Comment: @Reneo: The issue is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087623/is-function-f-mathbb-c-0-rightarrow-mathbb-c-prescribed-by-z-rightarrow