# Prove that $f(z)$ is not continuous at $z=i$ where $f(z)=\frac{3z^4 -2z^3 +8z^2 -2z +5}{z-i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, continuity

I tried to simplify it

$$f(z)=\frac{3z^4 -2z^3 +8z^2 -2z +5}{z-i}$$
$$f(z)=\frac{{3z^2 -2z +5}{z^2+1}}{z-i}$$
$$f(z)=\frac{(3z^2 -2z +5)(z+i)(z-i)}{z-i}$$

$$f(z)=(3z^2-2z+5)(z+i)$$

How to prove that it won't be continuous at $i$ from here on?

Comment: $$3z^4 + 8z^2 + 5 - 2z(z^2 + 1) = (z^2 + 1)(3z^2 + 5) - 2z(z^2 + 1) = (z-i)(z+i)(3z^2 - 2z + 5) = (z-i)(z+i)(3z - 5)(z+1)$$
So, we can write $f(x) = (z+i)(3z - 5)(z+1)$ and therefore, I think it is continuous everywhere.

Comment: @Snowball The question says it is supposed to be discontinuous at z=i but putting that in f(z) after simplifying doesn't give 0. Even when applying limits I can't understand how to prove it.

Comment: Is $f$ defined at $z=i$?

Comment: It's not continuous at $z=i$, but it's nevertheless weird to say that it's **dis**continuous there. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087623/is-function-f-mathbb-c-0-rightarrow-mathbb-c-prescribed-by-z-rightarrow).

Answer (score 2):

$$f(z) = \left\{ \begin{aligned} (z+i)(3z-5)(z+1), \quad z & \ne i \\
\text{undefined}, \quad z & =i
\end{aligned} \right.$$

Since $f(z)$ is undefined at $z=i$, it cannot be continuous there.

It is, though, a removable discontinuity.  Just define it to be $\lim_{z\to i} f(z).$

Comment: can you please explain how it is undefined at _z=i_ ?

Comment: @yesiam That's because you can't put $z=i$ in $\frac{3z^4 -2z^3 +8z^2 -2z +5}{z-i}$.

Comment: @mjw So to check if a function is defined at a point we put the point in the initial equation and not the simplified one? Sorry I'm a bit rusty with the concepts.

Comment: Well, the definition of $f(z)$ is a fraction where the numerator and denominator are both zero at $z=i$.  Because the denominator is zero, the function is not well defined there.  Of course, this fraction has a finite limit, and we can *define* $f(z)$ to be the value of the limit, but we need to define it to remove the 'singularity'.  It's a subtle point, but I think that is what the question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the limit definition of continuity.

> A function $f$ is continuous at $x=c$ iff $$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$$

When $f(c)$ is not defined, it doesn't make sense to compare it to the limit. So, the function is not continuous. $\square $

However, it is a removable discontinuity as we can **define** (this function is different from the original function) $f(z)$ to be the original fraction for $x\neq i$ and $f(i)$ as the limit of $f(z)$ as $z\to i$.

---

Also, kudos to you to post the problem with context and details. A great welcome to MathSE!

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)