# Given the function $f(x,y)=\frac{5xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$, argue analytically, if the discontinuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$ is avoidable or unavoidable.

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

It is clear that $f(0,0)$ does not exist, and therefore the function is discontinuous. Now to know if the discontinuity is avoidable or inevitable, we must see that the limit at that point exists or not. To see the above we will use polars.
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{5xy^2}{x^2+y^2}&=\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{5(r\cos(\theta))(r\sin(\theta))^2}{(r\cos(\theta))^2+(r\sin(\theta))^2}\\
                                                     & =\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{5r^3\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{r^2(\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta))}\\
                                                     & =\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{5r^3\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{r^2}\\
                                                     & =\lim_{r\rightarrow0}5r\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)=0.
\end{align*}
Now let's test for the definition $\epsilon-\delta$, to see that the limit exists and is zero.
\begin{align*}
    \left|\frac{5xy^2}{x^2+y^2}-0\right| & =\left|\frac{5xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\\
                                         & =\frac{5|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2}\\
                                         & \leq 5|x| \text{ since $y^2\leq x^2+y^2$}\\
                                         & \leq 5\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \text{ since $|x|\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$}\\
                                         & <5\delta = \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Therefore we have:
\begin{align*}
    \forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0 \text{ such that, if } 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x,y)-0| &\leq5 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
    &<5 \delta = 5\left(\frac{\epsilon}{5}\right)=\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Thus the limit exists and is zero, therefore the discontinuity of $f$ is avoidable.

I think this is the correct solution, I await your comments. If anyone has a different solution or correction of my work I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your proofs (the analytic proof, and the proof using polar coordinates)  that $\lim_{(x,y) f(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}=0$ are correct.

Comment: It is that I wrote it wrong because it must go $\cos^2{\theta}+r^2 \sin^{2}{\theta}=1$ (I already corrected it)

Comment: I see that. And to make it perfect you could also note that the limit is zero, as the factor  $\cos{\theta}\sin^2{\theta}$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is wrong; since $f$ is undefined at $(0,0)$, it is neither continuous nor discontinuous at that point.

Otherwise, you proved correctly that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=0$ and that therefore you can extend $f$ in such a way that it becomes continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: +1. More about the first point can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087623/is-function-f-mathbb-c-0-rightarrow-mathbb-c-prescribed-by-z-rightarrow

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you.

Comment: The first thing I say is exactly what you say, because I say it does not exist and it is obvious why

Comment: And since $f$ is undefined at $(0,0)$ it makes no sense to talk about continuity at that point.

Comment: The title explains well what you are looking for (with all due respect my comment)

Comment: @BML: The first (or maybe second) thing you say is “therefore the function is discontinuous”, and it's this phrasing that is arguably wrong (as José is pointing out), since the function actually is continuous – after all, it's continuous at every point of its domain! See the question that I linked to.

Comment: Sure the function is continuous in its domain, but we are talking about the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: @BML: Which is not in the domain, which is why it's inappropriate to say that it's discontinuous there. It's would be weird for a continuous function to have discontinuities, don't you think? Again, *see the question that I linked to* for more discussion.

Comment: I understand what they want to tell me, but I insist, I am talking about the point $(0,0)$ (not the domain of $f$) and I am not proving that it is continuous or not.

Comment: But you wrote “and therefore the function is discontinuous”.

Comment: I mean in the point, because in the writing you should avoid fillers ...

Comment: Which point? The point $(0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: Then, as I wrote in my answer, you are wrong. The function $f$ is *not* discontinuous at $(0,0)$ (and neither it is continuous at that point).

Comment: Okay, I understand what you want to tell me and I think the problem is writing the ideas, in any case thank you for your comments.